# Docker `/bin/sh: 1: [<executable>, : not found`

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I want to run an executable installed with pip. Running the following image gives me `/bin/sh: 1: [hbd,: not found`:

```
FROM python:3.8.3-slim-buster

WORKDIR /data

COPY cookies.txt /data/cookies.txt

RUN python3.8 -m pip install humblebundle-downloader

CMD ["hbd", "download", "--cookie-file", "/data/cookies.txt", "--library-path", "/data" "--progress", "--update"]
```

I've tried `CMD ["/usr/local/bin/python3.8", "-m", "hbd", "download",...` and `CMD python -m hbd download...` and similar as well. Resulting in `/bin/sh: 1: [/usr/local/bin/python3.8,: not found` etc.

If I replace `CMD ...` with `CMD which python3.8 && which hbd && find / -executable -type f -name hbd` I get:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.8
/usr/local/bin/hbd
/usr/local/bin/hbd
```

Which to me, tells me that the executables are there!?

How do I execute the, clearly present, executable?

I'm at my wits' end. Thank you!

Edit:
I tried with the 'non-slim' version of the base image, i.e `FROM python:3.8.5-buster`, no dice.

Comment: It looks like there is a missing comma `,` between `"/data"` and `"--progress"`.  That would cause this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello I trying your Dockerfile it failed, I ran a shell inside the instead and tried hbd, the command was available just fine:

```
docker run -ti 7552b04ea25b sh
# hbd
usage: hbd [-h] {download} ...
hbd: error: the following arguments are required: action
```

I then tried without the quote, square brackets and commas, it worked:

```
CMD hbd download --cookie-file /data/cookies.txt --library-path /data --progress --update
```

I tried again with your CMD, it failed, I shortened it, it worked, with a few trial and errors I finally I saw that you forgot a comma between 2 arguments. You command shall be (notice the comma between 2 arguments has been added):

```
CMD ["hbd", "download", "--cookie-file", "/data/cookies.txt", "--library-path", "/data", "--progress", "--update"]
```

So next time, try you hypothesis and try to investigate yourself:

Hypothesis: The executable is not found ? Then test it by checking the command inside the container by running a shell inside it. Conclusion: path & executable are found.

Hypothesis: CMD syntax is wrong ? Let's try a different syntax. It works with CMD hbd. So yes obvious that was the CMD syntax... Let's try to debug it and craft it by dichotomy... Hey a comma is missing ;) Problem solved.

Comment: OMG! I've been staring at it for, I don't know how long!! I feel like I've been through your recommended steps of investigation a hundred times, but somehow missed the damn ','! Thank you! 
Others have caught the error as well, however, the timestamp shows you as being the first. Again, thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. We all have this moment where you know we realize it was just a comma or something.

Answer (score 1):

`CMD ["hbd", "download", "--cookie-file", "/data/cookies.txt", "--library-path", "/data" "--progress", "--update"]`

Should be

`CMD ["hbd", "download", "--cookie-file", "/data/cookies.txt", "--library-path", "/data", "--progress", "--update"]`

What I think is happening is that since `CMD` is not specified as a valid JSON array, it is interpreted as a normal command that begins with `[` which is of course not valid.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be because of which the environment variables are not set or the path is not exported to the environment. Trying either of these, might help

Comment: Thank you. 
I don't think it's the PATH, as I'm using the full path of the executable. Which environment variables do you think it could be?

Comment: are you sure the python is in **/usr/local/bin/** and if that is the case try to set this path in /etc/environment file and check? Though you tried giving full path, just try this once.

Comment: Yes, pretty sure. As stated, if i replace the `CMD ...` with `which ...`/`find` etc. I get the correct output

Comment: The path is fine, see my other answer, I managed to run the executable just fine. it is the syntax you used for the CMD command.